# how to compress multiples files present in subfolders with their respective file's names. zip files should contain in respective sub folders

Tags: python

I am very new in python pls anyone tell me how to compress files present in subfolders respectively below is my code, but it won't work can anyone guide me

```
import os
import zipfile

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk('DATA'):

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with zipfile.ZipFile(file[0:-4] + '.zip', 'w') as fzip:
                fzip.write(os.path.join(folder, file),
                                os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file), 'DATA'),
                                compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

.txt file path:-  
DATA\1\AA.txt 
DATA\2\AB.txt 
DATA\3\AC.txt
DATA\4\AD.txt 
DATA\5\AE.txt 
DATA\6\AF.txt 
DATA\7\AG.txt

zip file should be created in: -

D:\DATA\1\AA.txt & AA.zip 
D:\DATA\2\AB.txt & AB.zip 
D:\DATA\3\AC.txt & AC.zip 
D:\DATA\4\AD.txt & AD.zip 
D:\DATA\5\AE.txt & AE.zip
D:\DATA\6\AF.txt & AF.zip 
D:\DATA\7\AG.txt & AG.zip
```

Comment: Could you please detail what exactly is "not working"? Are the zip files not being created correctly? Are they being saved to the wrong directory?

Comment: Only one last file got zip but with that folder name and also in wrong path means before data folder that file got zip. I want to zip only all .txt files inside that folder and that zip file should be placed under that same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, the `.zip` files weren't being saved into the same directories as the `.txt` files. The following code should solve that issue for you. It combines the `folder` and `file` objects to create the new paths.

```py
import os
import zipfile

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk('DATA'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            # specify path of zip file: Split by "." and take first item to remove the ".txt"
            zip_path = os.path.join(folder, file.replace(".txt", ".zip"))
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w') as fzip:
                fzip.write(
                    os.path.join(folder, file),
                    os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file), 'DATA'), 
                    compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
                )
```

In the future I'd recommend using `glob` to fix this. `glob` avoids the separation of the directories and files.

Comment: Thank you so much from so many days I am looking for the solution but today I got solution with help of you really thank you.